# redirect_to doesnt take effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails

I have a controller and inside the controller

```
def publish
  post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  post.update(published: true, published_at: Time.now)
  redirect_to edit_post_path(post)
end

def unpublish
  post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  post.update(published: false, published_at: nil)
  redirect_to edit_post_path(post)
end
```

And my stimulus controller "publishers_controller"

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import log from "stimulus_reflex/javascript/log";

// Connects to data-controller="publishers"
export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    console.log("Connected")
  }

  publish(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const postId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-post-id");
    const url = `/posts/${postId}/publish`; 

    fetch(url, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRF-Token": document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
      },
    })
      
  }

  unpublish(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const postId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-post-id');
    const url = `/posts/${postId}/unpublish`;
    fetch(url, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRF-Token": document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
      },
    })
    
    }
}
```

this is my route.rb

```
scope module: "authors" do
    resources :posts do
      put "publish", to: "posts#publish"
      put "unpublish", to: "posts#unpublish"
      resources :elements do
      end
    end
  end
```

And where i use it edit.html.erb

```
<div class="card-footer">
        <% if @post.published? %>
          <a
            href="#"
            class="btn btn-danger d-block my-4"
            data-action="click->publishers#unpublish"
            data-post-id="<%= @post.id %>"
          >Unpublish</a>
        <% else %>
          <a
            href="#"
            class="btn btn-success d-block my-4"
            data-action="click->publishers#publish"
            data-post-id="<%= @post.id %>"
          >Publish</a>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

Everything works good but when i try to send a request from UI **publish** or **unpublish**, it doesn't load the UI for me. Only when i refresh the page it shows publish state changed . I want that without me manually refresh the page, whenever **state for publish**  will change it should reflect it.  And i though by using **redirect_to** would be enough.

Comment: `fetch` doesn't update your browser, you have to handle the response yourself https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch . also note that you're not sending or responding with any json so `"application/json"` seems unnecessary, you'd be better off without this stimulus controller and just make two buttons with `button_to`.

Comment: Also you should never just assume that updating a record will always be successful.